# How to establish a GIOstream and GDBusConnection to a cellular modem device

Tags: c, modem, glib

I am trying to use [libmm-glib documentation](https://developer-old.gnome.org/libmm-glib/unstable/) to put together a program to gather cellular modem information on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04). My question is how do I establish a GIOStream, and subsequently a GDBusConnection to the device. Namely, my device when pinged from the command line shows 2 tty devies, but both are labelled as "ignore" (dev/ttyUSB4,dev/ttyUSB1). I have also tried using /dev/cdc-wdm0 to initialize the Gfile with no success.

Steps (code below):

1. get a GFile associated with the modem

   **a. What path should I use to the device?**
2. construct a GIOStream to the modem with the GFile
3. construct a DBusConnection with the GIOStream
4. contruct a MMManager with the DBusConnection
5. Use MMManager to query the specific modem.

```
gcc main.c -I/usr/include/libmm-glib -I/usr/include/ModemManager -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 -lz -lgio-2.0 -lpthread -lmm-glib
```

```
#include <libmm-glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
//#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    printf("begin 1\n");

    GCancellable                     *cancellable;
    GError                           **ppError;
    MMManager                        *pManager;
    GDBusAuthObserver                *observer;
    GDBusObjectManagerClientFlags    flags = G_DBUS_OBJECT_MANAGER_CLIENT_FLAGS_NONE;
    const gchar                      *guid  = NULL; 
    //g_type_init(); 
    //GFile * save = g_file_new_for_path("/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/3");
    //GFile * save = g_file_new_for_path("/sys/devices/platform/soc@0/32c00000.bus/32e50000.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.3");
    GFile * save = g_file_new_for_path("/dev/ttyUSB0");


    if(save == NULL)
    {
        printf("null GFile\n");
    }    
    else
    {
        printf("GFile OK\n");

    }
    GFileIOStream *pStream = g_file_open_readwrite(save, NULL, NULL);

    if(pStream == NULL)
    {
        printf("null pStream\n");
    }    
    else
    {
        printf("pStream OK\n");
    }
    
    GDBusConnection *pConnection= g_dbus_connection_new_sync(pStream,
                                                      guid, // for authent. as a server
                                                      flags,
                                                      NULL, // observer,
                                                      NULL, // cancellable,
                                                      ppError);

    if(pConnection == NULL)
    {
        printf("null GDBusConnection\n");
    }

    pManager = mm_manager_new_sync(pConnection,
                                   flags,
                                   cancellable,
                                   ppError);

    if(pManager == NULL)
    {
        printf("null pManager\n");
    }

    mm_manager_scan_devices_sync(pManager,
                 cancellable,
                 ppError);

    MMObject modem;

    printf("d\n");

    //const gchar* pChar = mm_object_get_path(&modem);

    //free resources here
    
    printf("end\n");
    return(0);
}
```

```
  -----------------------------
  General  |              path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/3
           |         device id: 
  -----------------------------
  Hardware |      manufacturer: Telit
           |             model: LE910C4-NF
           | firmware revision: 25.21.660  1  [Mar 04 2021 12:00:00]
           |    carrier config: default
           |      h/w revision: 1.30
           |         supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |           current: gsm-umts, lte
           |      equipment id: 
  -----------------------------
  System   |            device: /sys/devices/platform/soc@0/32c00000.bus/32e50000.usb/ci_hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.3
           |           drivers: qmi_wwan, option
           |            plugin: telit
           |      primary port: cdc-wdm0
           |             ports: cdc-wdm0 (qmi), ttyUSB0 (ignored), ttyUSB1 (gps),
           |                    ttyUSB4 (ignored), wwan0 (net)
  -----------------------------
  Status   |             state: failed
           |     failed reason: sim-missing
           |       power state: on
           |    signal quality: 0% (cached)
  -----------------------------
  Modes    |         supported: allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                    allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                    allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                    allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |           current: allowed: any; preferred: none
  -----------------------------
  Bands    |         supported: utran-4, utran-5, utran-2, eutran-2, eutran-4, eutran-5,
           |                    eutran-12, eutran-13, eutran-14, eutran-66, eutran-71
  -----------------------------
  IP       |         supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  -----------------------------
  SIM      |    sim slot paths: slot 1: none (active)
           |                    slot 2: none
```

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. Questions on this site should have a single answer. Please edit your question to focus on a single question in the post.

Comment: I have tried to narrow the scope to "how to establish a GIOStream to a cellular modem". Downvotes are always appreciated.

Comment: I think the issue is this question is too broad. I'd recommend narrowing it down to a minimal example (your step 1 and 2 above) that just opens the modem and expand with new questions. Does this help? https://github.com/bm16ton/yoga-c630-network-manager/blob/6257473a5eb8a1a5d939a16a01f8178185d77e78/src/devices/wwan/nm-modem-manager.c

Comment: thank you i will try to refine it per your recommendation.

Comment: "What path should I use to the device?" that is going to be OS specific (macOS, Ubuntu 20.04, Raspbian X.Y). So you need to sort out what driver is supplying you the /dev/ file to the modem.

Comment: I think thats already been sorted out by the mmcli output i provided. I know the device exists at /dev/cdc-wdm0. However it also has listed interfaces on /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyUSB4, however it labels them as ignored. So thats my first area of uncertainty. I am currently using /dev/cdc-wdm0 to get to the g_dbus_connection_new_sync() stage, which is failing with the following output, which confuses me as part of it is complaining about a GDBusObjectManagerClientFlags, while the prototype is defined as accepting a GDBusConnectionFlags

Comment: GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 03:54:48.507: _g_dbus_worker_do_read_cb: error determining bytes needed: Unable to determine message blob length - given blob is malformed
null GDBusConnection(error)
(process:4767): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 03:54:48.508: value "((GDBusObjectManagerClientFlags) 8)" of type 'GDBusObjectManagerClientFlags' is invalid or out of range for property 'flags' of type 'GDBusObjectManagerClientFlags'
(process:4767): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 03:54:48.508: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
null pManager